# Linking to Stack Overflow Answers as additional information

Tags: discussion, support, linked-questions

It's about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25612986/3366929). (mine)

The User asking the question has chosen to give a plugin a try, which did the job and added that as his own answer, which is fine, as far as I know. But the reason to choose a plugin was just wrong.

So I added my answer and he accepted it.

Then I run thru his code again and I thought that linking to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899200/is-there-a-naming-convention-for-mysql) (I also linked to both involved user profiles) would be good additional information, because a part of the error was kind of related to naming conventions.

The main mistake leading the user to Stack Overflow comes from a lack of knowledge, which I think having answered correctly.

**Now, my question is: Is this good practice or even forbidden?**

Comment: Linking is fine, copying is not so fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as that's not *the only thing you put in the answer*, it's fine.

If that's the only thing in your answer, then

1. It's link-only and subject to deletion, and
2. The question you're answering is a duplicate.

Answering a question with someone else's answer **is plagiarism**, and is unacceptable, but linking to tangentially related questions that may help anyone who comes across the question resolve the issue is fine and even encouraged.

Comment: Ok, Thx, that is answering my question. btw copy/paste??? really??